# Count variable PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a list of holidays. If a holiday falls between my Week beginning date and week ending date then hours awarded would be 8.

Problem I am having is I can display 8 hours  ( this is include file and the value is being displayed on another PHP document ) however if I have multiple holidays for a week it still only displays 8. I would like to display

One Holiday would be 8 hours
Two Holidays would be 16 Hours
Three Holidays would be  32 hours

and so on and so forth

I was messing around with += it would work however it would display the total amount for every week

Here is my code

```
<?

//Holiday List for 2015

//Hours for Holiday

$TestHol = "2015-03-17";
$TestHol2 = "2015-03-16";
$TestHol3 = "2015-03-06";
$NY = "2015-01-01";
$Mem = "2015-05-26";
$V1 = "2015-06-27";
$V2 = "2015-06-30";
$V3 = "2015-07-01";
$V4 = "2015-07-02";
$V5 = "2015-07-03";
$In = "2015-07-04";
$Lab = "2015-09-01";
$Thx = "2015-11-27";
$ThxF = "2015-11-28";
$Chev = "2015-12-24";
$Ch = "2015-12-25";
$V6 = "2015-12-29";
$V7 = "2015-12-30";
$V8 = "2015-12-31";

$holhour = 0;

if(($TestHol>$WBDATE) && ($TestHol<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($TestHol2>$WBDATE) && ($TestHol2<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($TestHol3>$WBDATE) && ($TestHol3<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;  
elseif(($NY>$WBDATE) && ($NY<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($Mem>$WBDATE) && ($Mem<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($V1>$WBDATE) && ($V2<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($V2>$WBDATE) && ($V2<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($V3>$WBDATE) && ($V3<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($V4>$WBDATE) && ($V4<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($V5>$WBDATE) && ($V5<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($In>$WBDATE) && ($In<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($Lab>$WBDATE) && ($Lab<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($Thx>$WBDATE) && ($Thx<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($ThxF>$WBDATE) && ($ThxF<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($Chev>$WBDATE) && ($Chev<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($Ch>$WBDATE) && ($Ch<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($V6>$WBDATE) && ($V6<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($V7l>$WBDATE) && ($V7<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
elseif(($V8>$WBDATE) && ($V8<$WEDATE)):
 $holhour = 8;
else :
 $holhour = 0;
endif; 



 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not incrementing $holhour value. You are just assigning 8 to it every time. modify it to $holhour = $holhour + 8; - whenever you want to add one more holiday. (in all of your if and elseif statements, but not in last else - that's what i guess)

Comment: I was attempting to do this at the end 

$holhour +=$holhour

Comment: see the edited answer and try incrementing the value in all if and elseif's